Can the sum of a nonlinear irreducible character's values on $Z(\chi)$ be zero?
I need a lemma for a research problem.  Suppose that I sum the values of a nonlinear irreducible character $\chi$ of a finite group over the center of that character $Z(\chi)$.  Is it possible for the resulting values to sum to zero?  If so, under what conditions would this occur?  For the purposes of my research, I would like for this NOT to happen.

You should include your own thoughts/attempt.

Is $Z(\chi)$ defined as ${g\in G: |\chi(g)|=|\chi(1)|}$?

@coiso Yes, that's it.

This sum of values is not equal to zero if and only if $\chi$ is constant over $Z(\chi)$.
First, write the restriction of $\chi$ to $Z(\chi)$ as $\chi_{Z(\chi)}=\chi(1)\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a linear character of $Z(\chi)$. Then, your sum is equal to
$$\sum_{g\in Z(\chi)}\chi_{Z(\chi)}(g)=|Z(\chi)|[\chi_{Z(\chi)},1_{Z(\chi)}]=|Z(\chi)|\chi(1)[\lambda,1_{Z(\chi)}].$$
As both $\lambda$ and $1_{Z(\chi)}$ are irreducible characters, its inner product is equal to $0$ unless $\lambda=1_{Z(\chi)}$, but this occurs if and only if $\chi$ is constant over $Z(\chi)$. Also, notice that this does not depend on the degree of $\chi$.

Thanks, Deif.  This is great.  For which finite groups, if any, can we be guaranteed an irreducible character that is NOT constant over its center?

In the spirit of offering my own thoughts, just let me say that I am working with a group where at least one irreducible character does not vanish off its own center.

@Hanklin I don't know if there is some general criteria for characterizing this property. Note that for example the nonlinear character of $Q_8$ is not constant over its center. But, this group does not satisfy the property mentioned in your second comment.

According to Problem 5.11 in Isaacs CTFG on page 75, if $N\triangleleft G$ and $\chi\in \text{Irr}(G),$ and if $[\chi_N,1_N]\neq 0,$ then $N\subseteq \text{Ker} \chi$.  With $N=Z(\chi)$, this implies that if $Z(\chi)\neq \text{Ker} \chi$, then $\chi$ is not constant over $Z(\chi)$.  So now I'm wondering about the conditions under which $Z(\chi)=\text{Ker} \chi$.
